# What regulates these two methods of splicing?

Tags: gene-regulation, splicing

Alternative splicing can shuffle the exon order and select from the exon sequence of a single gene site to provide a combinatorial selection of possible transcription products from the one gene. Can intergenic trans splicing can do this starting from multiple gene sites?

What regulates these two "non linear" gene combination, transcript-splicing processes?

Comment: Are you referring to [trans splicing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-splicing)?

Answer (score 1):

As Alan Boyd said, this process is called trans splicing where exons of different RNAs are joined together. Physical proximity is conducive for trans-splicing. This [study](http://rnajournal.cshlp.org/content/14/6/1081.full) shows that trans-splicing frequency is higher if the genes are proximal. Proximity not only means closer in the genome but also the 3D proximity governed by chromosomal interactions.

Now, what factors  **promote** trans splicing is not properly understood.